# BeforeUpdate hook never called

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm using gorm.io library, version 1.20.8, the last one available at the moment.
I have this, simplified, model:

```
type ExternalUser struct {
    BaseModel
    Name            string `gorm:"type:char(255);uniqueIndex:compositeIndex;not null"`
    Password        string
    HashPassword    string
}
```

with this BeforeUpdate function

```
func (user *ExternalUser) BeforeUpdate(tx *gorm.DB) error {
        pass, _ := utils.HashPassword(user.Password)
        tx.Statement.SetColumn("HashPassword", pass)
        encryptedPass := utils.EncryptString(user.Password)
        tx.Statement.SetColumn("Password", encryptedPass)
    return nil
}
```

But it seems it is never been called, and I cannot understand why.
This is the update function that I call:

```
func UpdateExternalUser(dataForm command.ExternalUserUpdate, externalUserID string, userId uuid.UUID) (int64, error) {
    dataForm.UpdatedUserID = userId
    result := database.DB().Table("external_user").Where("id=?", externalUserID).Updates(&dataForm)
    if err := result.Error; err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }
    row := result.RowsAffected
    return row, nil
}
```

The BeforeCreate hook works fine.

The BaseModel type in the model above is defined like this:

```
type BaseModel struct {
    ID            uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:char(36);primary_key;"`
    Version       int64     `gorm:"not null;"`
    CreatedAt     time.Time `gorm:"index;"`
    UpdatedAt     time.Time `gorm:"index;"`
    CreatedUserID uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:char(36);index;not null;"`
    UpdatedUserID uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:char(36);index;not null;"`
}

func (BaseModel *BaseModel) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    newUUID := uuid.NewV4()
    tx.Statement.SetColumn("ID", newUUID)
    tx.Statement.SetColumn("Version", 0)
    return nil
}
```

**UPDATE**

as a comment point out I changed the query as the follow:

```
result := database.DB().Model(&model.ExternalUser{}).Where("id=?", externalUserID).Updates(&dataForm)
```

and now indeed the hook take place, but I got a panic error, I suppose becasue the model struct I passed **Model(&model.ExternalUser{})** is empty.

Here the passing error message:

```
2020/12/18 20:31:32 [Recovery] 2020/12/18 - 20:31:32 panic recovered:
PUT /core/api/v1/external-user/4dd6223f-0546-4e20-a6e1-9cd89499b281 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8090
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 407
Content-Type: application/json
Postman-Token: 9844ea91-5e25-4123-a950-0a19f80352a1
Uber-Trace-Id: 77b3baa8890e5788:7ada969a1b89b7e5:77b3baa8890e5788:1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8


reflect: call of reflect.Value.Field on string Value
/usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:850 (0x411ac04)
        Value.Field: panic(&ValueError{"reflect.Value.Field", v.kind()})
/Users/xxxx/Project/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.20.8/schema/field.go:393 (0x4a41a93)
        (*Field).setupValuerAndSetter.func2: fieldValue := reflect.Indirect(value).Field(field.StructField.Index[0]).Field(field.StructField.Index[1])
/Users/xxxx/Project/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.20.8/callbacks/update.go:230 (0x4ae6f74)
        ConvertToAssignments: value, isZero := field.ValueOf(updatingValue)
/Users/xxxx/Project/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/driver/mysql@v1.0.3/update_with_order_by_limit.go:20 (0x4aeeef2)
        Update: if set := callbacks.ConvertToAssignments(db.Statement); len(set) != 0 {
/Users/xxxx/Project/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.20.8/callbacks.go:105 (0x4a56f33)
        (*processor).Execute: f(db)
/Users/xxxx/Project/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.20.8/finisher_api.go:318 (0x4a61a27)
        (*DB).Updates: tx.callbacks.Update().Execute(tx)
```

**UPDATE/2**

After some tests I see that using this line everything works:

```
result := database.DB().Model(&model.ExternalUser{}).Where("id = ?", externalUserID).Updates(model.ExternalUser{Name: dataForm.Name, Password: dataForm.Password})
```

But in this case I'm being forced to specify each field in the Updates clausole, instead of passing just the struct.

Comment: is this  result.RowsAffected greather than 0 ?

Comment: yes, I change always some fields as test

Comment: maybe it is because you have used `database.DB().Table("external_user")` instead of `database.DB().Model(dataForm)`

Comment: the thing is dataform is not the model, it's a struct this is why I used Table("external_user") instead of the model. But I'll update the orginal message, thanks!

Comment: have you tried either `result := database.DB().Model(model.ExternalUser{}).Where("id=?", externalUserID).Updates(dataForm)` or `externalUser := model.ExternalUser{ID: externalUserID}   database.DB().Model(&externalUser).Updates(dataForm)`?

Comment: Hi Emin, yes the first one I got the same error message, while the latter I cannot do it because, and this is strange, I cannot get the ID even if is encapsulate in BaseModel, but i don't think it is gonna chagne something. mysql driver is 1.5.0, the latest

Comment: @EminLaletovic The second options you mention above gives me this error: cannot use promoted field BaseModel.ID in struct literal of type model.ExternalUser

Comment: A quick fix could be to use a package like this https://github.com/jinzhu/copier to copy from/to the desired type. though, what is your reason to use different struct types for db storage and the post form decoding ?

Comment: thanks for the hint @mh-cbon I'll give it a try, about your question, I always prefer to keep separate the DB model from the data struct that I use in REST.